# Minimal regular expression that matches a given set of words

Tags: optimization, regular-expressions, strings, exact-string-matching

I have a dictionary-like regular expression, an "or chain" of words,

```
word1|word2|word3|...
```

Unfortunately, the chain is too large.  I'd like to find the minimal regular expression that is equivalent.  How can do I do that?

You should think of this as a regex like `/^(word1|word2|word3)$/`.  I have a dictionary of words, and I want a minimal regex that will match if and only if the input string is a word in that dictionary.  By minimal, I want the shortest regex that matches all words in the dictionary (and nothing else).  I need a regex, not some other representation.

The words come from SQL `SELECT DISTINCT word FROM t ORDER BY length DESC, word` so I'm hoping for a solution that is optimized to practical use.

I was able to identify some heuristics that work for some special cases, but not a general algorithm:

- It's easy to deal with accented variations: `mãe|mae` becomes `ma[ãe]e`).  This works fine.
- Also, `ABCCC|ABCC|ABC|DF` can be automatically reduced to (output) `ABC{1,3}|DF` or `AB(?:C|CC|CCC)|DF`

As @Raphael noted, "minimizing regular expressions is hard", so it is important the focus on non-generic solutions.

I found a web page that describes how  to [convert a regex to NFA or DFA](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa), but that doesn't help me get back a minimal regular expression.  I'm willing to use an existing library, such as [this PHP one](https://github.com/KendallHopkins/FormalTheory), but how do I use the library for this purpose?

Comment: For your particular case(finite number of strings), it's not known if the min regular expression is NP-hard. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16860/minimizing-size-of-regular-expression-for-finite-sets

Comment: Your special case is also likely to be hard.

Comment: @Chao Xu: please consider converting your comment into an answer. As you stated, it is an unresolved research problem in theoretical computer science.

Comment: The second example of simplification the OP found is referred to as "analogue to Horner's rule" in: Keith Ellul, Bryan Krawetz, Jeffrey Shallit, Ming-wei Wang:
Regular Expressions: New Results and Open Problems. Journal of Automata, Languages and Combinatorics 10(4): 407-437 (2005)